# How to make card program have two players?

Tags: c

I posted earlier, but I am going to ask a more specific question. I have my game set up right now to play cards, but I can't figure out how to deal cards for two players and make sure they don't have the same cards. thanks for your input!

code for the print function:

```
void print_hand( int hand[], int size )


{
 int i ;


for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
 {

player = print_card( hand[i] ) ;

  putchar( '\n' ) ;
 }
}
```

all of my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DECK_SIZE 52

void init_deck( int deck[] , int size ) ;
void shuffle_deck( int deck[] , int size ) ;
void sort_hand( int hand[] , int size ) ;
void print_hand( int hand[] , int size ) ;
void print_card( int card ) ;

main()
{
  int deck[DECK_SIZE] ;

    char c;
    printf("This game gives each user 5 cards and then compares the hands against eachother, and then determines who has the hand with the highest value\n");
    printf(" If you would like to play, please enter yes, if not, enter no\n");
/* asks the user to play, if not then stops program*/

  srand( time( NULL ) ) ;
  // sets up the random number generator

  init_deck( deck , DECK_SIZE ) ;
  // calls the initialize deck function


  shuffle_deck( deck , DECK_SIZE ) ;
  // calls the shuffle deck function



  print_hand( deck , DECK_SIZE ) ;
  // prints out the users hand
  putchar( '\n' ) ;
  // prints each card on a seperate line.
}

void init_deck( int deck[] , int size )
// creates the deck function

{
  int i ;

  for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++ )
    deck[i] = i ;
    /* loops through 52 numbers and assigns a number to each card from the deck*/
}

void shuffle_deck( int deck[] , int size )
// creates the shuffle deck function

{
  int i , j , temp ;

  for( i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++ )
  {
    j = rand() % size ;
    temp = deck[i] ;
    deck[i] = deck[j] ;
    deck[j] = temp ;
    /* loops for all of the cards, and shuffles a card with another card from the deck randomly*/
  }
}


void print_hand( int hand[], int size )
// function for displaying the users hand.


{
  int i ;


  for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
  {

     print_card( hand[i] ) ;

    putchar( '\n' ) ;
    /* gives the player a random card for a total of five cards and displays each on a new line*/
  }
}

void print_card( int card )
// function for printing the cards with their number and suit


{
  char suit[4][9] =
    { "Spades" , "Hearts" , "Diamonds" , "Clubs" } ;
  char rank[13][6] =
    { "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" ,
      "Nine" , "Ten" , "Jack" , "Queen" , "King" , "Ace" } ;

  printf( "%s of %s" , rank[card%13] , suit[card/13] ) ;
  /* sets up two 2 dimensional arrays for assigning the suit to each card, and assigning it's rank. It thens prints the cards.*/
}
```

Comment: The code snippet you posted is unrelated to your question. Please post *all* the relevant code.

Comment: full code is now here

Answer (score 0):

Just an opinion, but I would suggest something a bit different. This is good program to try implementing a stack:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

Also, you don't necessarily need to bother with char arrays if you decide on an ordering for your suits. Say you pick spades,clubs,hearts,diamonds as highest to lowest, then you only need 4 * cards_per_suit bytes to store the deck. So you can make a stack for the deck, and then you can pick which ints (cards) to add to it at random. Then, when you pop from the stack, you never have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: I think I am getting what you are saying, I am trying to figure out how to implement one into my program, I might need a little help.

Comment: Lazy way: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/

But for a learning exercise, you need:
1. pointer to head of the stack
2. Array storing the stack (you don't need a linked list in this case)

Something as simple as:
`typedef struct _stack {
   size_t size;
   int *vals;
   int top;
   } Stack;`
could work.

Comment: I am having the issue of trying to find what parts of my program I need to use to make my stack function.   I have :  int popCard( int size*, int deck[])